# Text Interpolation is not updating in angular when an eventListener changes the value

Tags: angular, typescript, interpolation

I have two angular apps one of which is the parent with and iframe that loads the child app.  The HTML is extremely basic:

```
<div class="first">
    <label>{{postedMessage}}</label>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <iframe src="http://localhost:4200/" id="displayFrame" title="Compass" width="70%" 
    float="right" height="750px"></iframe>
</div>
```

The parent app is listening for a postMessage() event from the child, in this case localhost:4200.  I know the postMessage eventListener is working because when the parent does a console.log(JSON.stringify(event)) it logs as expected.  The event listener also updates the value of postedMessage at the same time, but it's not updating on the UI.  I cannot figure out why.  I tried adding a button that updates the value in the same way (except it's not from an event) when the (click) method is called, and that works exactly as expected.

Here is what the typescript looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: ['']
})
export class TestComponent {
  postedMessage: string = 'This is a test string';

    constructor() {
        window.addEventListener("message", this.handleEvent, false);
    }

  handleEvent(event: MessageEvent) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    this.postedMessage = (JSON.stringify(event));
  }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas why this wouldn't be working, it would be very much appreciated!  Thanks

To answer carl's answer, I cannot provide the actual child app code.  In the most basic fashion though, it would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<button (click)="postMessage()">Test</button>
```

Typescript:

```
postMessage() {
    // This is where I'd calculate the data being sent to the parent
    data: string; // Some JSON string
    window.parent.postMessage(data, this.parentOrigin);
{
```

This would be the simplest way to show what is happening, but can write up a more in depth example if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you need to make your variable an Observable stream. Here's what I think would make your code work (NOTE: you will need rxjs installed to use `BehaviorSubject`):

```js
postedMessage: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('This is a test string');
```

To make sure the scope of your class component is referenced correctly in the handleEvent, make sure to bind `this`:

```js
constructor() {
    window.addEventListener("message", this.handleEvent.bind(this), false);
  }
```

Then in the `handleEvent` function do this:

```js
handleEvent(event: MessageEvent) {
    this.postedMessage.next(JSON.stringify(event));
  }
```

Also use an async pipe for your interpolation:

```html
<label>{{ postedMessage | async }}</label>
```

Comment: Thanks so much this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Create a relation between the parent and child. How?,
follow the steps below.

1 - import output
put the the code below in the child.ts file

```
import { Component Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class childTestComponent {

@Output() postMessage = new EventEmitter();

}
```

Step 2
Now go to the the child.html file and include this line of code

```
<button type="button" (click)="postMessage.emit()">Post Message</button>
```

Step 3
Now got in the parent's ts file and create an emitter like shown below. An Emitter is just a function but must start with "on"

```
onPostMessage() {
    *the rest of click event logic goes here*
     window.alert('button has been clicked');
   }
```

Step 4
Now go to the parent.html file and bind the emitter to the event on the line where you include the child component from, eg

```
<childComponent (postMessage)="onPostMessage()"></childComponent>
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll investigate these options.  My only thought though is that I know the parent is getting the data from the event the way it's already happening.  If you look at the handleEvent(event: MessageEvent) that I have in the parent, I'm logging exactly what the child posted.  And the logging works fine.  It's just not updating the text of the label on the next line when I do this.postedMessage = (JSON.stringify(event)); which is exactly what's being logged in the console.